# Read parquet partitioned file with dtplyr (lazy evalution) - R

Tags: r, parquet, dtplyr

I have those parquet files partitioned, so in multiple files.

I can read them with

```
df_test <- arrow::open_dataset('/path/topic.parquet',
                              partitioning=c("id"))
```

Since I have to do a lot of transformation before really using it I wanted to have a lazy DF thanks to `dtplyr`.

```
df_test_lazy <- arrow::open_dataset('/path/topic.parquet',
                              partitioning=c("id")) %>% lazy_dt()
```

I have the error

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x, ...) :
> cannot coerce class ‘c("FileSystemDataset", "Dataset", "ArrowObject", "R6")’ to a data.frame

How can I use `lazy_dt()` to read my data ?

Comment: The `arrow` package does not seem to provide `dtplyr` methods, only [`dplyr` methods](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/r/R/dplyr.R).

Comment: Can I transform the object in some way ?

Comment: Given that it's in arrow, wondering if you tried just using regular dplyr operations?